# Can't select spinner item in android

Tags: android

I select item from spinner but this item can't select and show. Help me (I write english not good)

This code.Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="15dp" >  
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spn_nganhang"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Activity

```
        ArrayList<String> arr_listbank = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayAdapter<String> arra_listbank = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, arr_listbank);  
     arra_listbank.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        Spinner spn_listbank = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spn_nganhang);
        spn_listbank.setAdapter(arra_listbank);
```

Full code: http://qhoang.org/paste/activity.txt

Help me.

Comment: Add something to ArrayList<String> arr_listbank = new ArrayList<String>();
  arr_listbank.add("Hello"); arr_listbank.add("Hi"); and see you are getting anything or not.

Comment: oh ... this right.
i don't understand why? 
can't you explained to me :D

Comment: You are constructing spinner from ArrayAdapter which takes arr_listbank as input for the list to do be displayed. In your above code it is empty. You need to populate it with the values you want to display in spinner, that is what I did. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add something to array list:

```
ArrayList<String> arr_listbank = new ArrayList<String>();

arr_listbank.add("Hello");

arr_listbank.add("Hi");
```

and see if you are getting anything or not.